# Pandas DataFrame: Collect Column Values to one Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

i have this table and the main problem is `ID ,W_Weight` are not the same length as `Class` column

> Note: Every Number of `ID` is associated with a `Class`, For example
>   ( the `ID 0` have `Class 1.0` and `ID 4` have `Class 5.0` )

```
   ID   W_Weight    Class

0   0   0.255265    1.0
1   0   0.273844    1.0
2   0   0.351219    1.0
3   0   0.262033    1.0
4   0   0.351219    5.0
5   0   0.258109    1.0
6   0   0.296328    5.0
7   0   0.351219    1.0
8   0   0.301208    1.0
9   0   0.273844    1.0
10  0   0.317767    1.0
11  1   0.299451    1.0
12  1   0.327183    5.0
13  1   0.391577    1.0
14  1   0.272526    1.0
15  1   0.412015    1.0
16  1   0.412015    1.0
17  1   0.287148    1.0
18  1   0.168667    5.0
19  1   0.257689    1.0
20  1   0.242609    1.0
21  2   0.190351    5.0
22  2   0.204205    5.0
23  2   0.254588    5.0
24  2   0.261904    1.0
25  2   0.195398    5.0
26  2   0.248913    5.0
27  2   0.161089    1.0
28  2   0.240355    5.0
29  2   0.261904    1.0
... ... ... ...
410722  32742   0.190023    NaN
410723  32742   0.190023    NaN
410724  32742   0.184970    NaN
410725  32742   0.166998    NaN
410726  32742   0.196789    NaN
410727  32742   0.171033    NaN
410728  32742   0.207060    NaN
410729  32742   0.171033    NaN
410730  32742   0.179186    NaN
410731  32742   0.207060    NaN
410732  32742   0.182852    NaN
410733  32742   0.146492    NaN
410734  32742   0.141293    NaN
410735  32742   0.193123    NaN
410736  32742   0.207060    NaN
410737  32742   0.092576    NaN
410738  32742   0.207060    NaN
410739  32742   0.160762    NaN
410740  32742   0.165249    NaN
410741  32742   0.207060    NaN
410742  32742   0.184970    NaN
410743  32742   0.147506    NaN
410744  32742   0.207060    NaN
410745  32742   0.190023    NaN
410746  32742   0.116286    NaN
410747  32742   0.070032    NaN
410748  32742   0.207060    NaN
410749  32742   0.166998    NaN
410750  32742   0.147506    NaN
410751  32742   0.207060    NaN
```

The desired table should look like this

> Note: the first line with index 0 is just an example, i want to do
>   this for all the data in `W_Weight` column

```
   ID                  W_Weight                                 Class
0   0   {0.25,0.27,0.35,0.26,0.35,0.25,0.29,0.35,0.30,0.27,0.31} 1.0
11  1   0.299451                                                 1.0
12  1   0.327183                                                 5.0
13  1   0.391577                                                 1.0
14  1   0.272526                                                 1.0
15  1   0.412015                                                 1.0
16  1   0.412015                                                 1.0
17  1   0.287148                                                 1.0
18  1   0.168667                                                 5.0
19  1   0.257689                                                 1.0
20  1   0.242609                                                 1.0
21  2   0.190351                                                 5.0
22  2   0.204205                                                 5.0
23  2   0.254588                                                 5.0
24  2   0.261904                                                 1.0
25  2   0.195398                                                 5.0
26  2   0.248913                                                 5.0
27  2   0.161089                                                 1.0
28  2   0.240355                                                 5.0
29  2   0.261904                                                 1.0
```

i'm doing this to match the `Class` with `ID and W_Weight` because i'm working on a classification with TensorFlow

Comment: Why would you do something so counterproductive? This is going to result in an object column and kill all performance/efficiency.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *wanting* to group by `Class` and aggregate `W_Weight`. But don't store this structure in a dataframe. There are other data types (e.g. `dict`) which can be used to achieve this. If you rephrased your question with this in mind, there is a straightforward solution.

Comment: you could try `df.groupby('ID').apply(set)` if you really want to

Comment: In your example, ID==0 is associated with two classes: 1.0 and 5.0, which contradicts your note. Please clarify.

Comment: Depending upon what you want to do later, it may be better to have the set stored as an array, in which case you would want `df.groupby('ID')['W_Weight'].unique()` so you can at least index the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You were correctly advised not to do what you attempted to do. Nonetheless, if you insist, here's a solution:

```
df.groupby('ID')['W_Weight'].apply(set)
#ID
#0    {0.255265, 0.351219, 0.25810900000000003, 0.26...
#1    {0.299451, 0.327183, 0.27252600000000005, 0.39...
```

Comment: As a trivial addendum, you can add `.to_dict()` to the end to convert this into a dictionary, which may be more suitable for subsequent manipulation.